# JavaScript ternary seems to ignore value passed in through object

Tags: javascript

This may be a hard question to answer, but I'm hoping somebody might have some insight.

The setup:

```
updateBackgroundImage: function(image_data) {
  let fabric_canvas;

  fabric_canvas = window.drawingPrompts[0];

  fabric_canvas.update({
   image_url: image_data.url,
   image_height: parseInt(image_data.dimensions.split('x')[1]),
   image_width: parseInt(image_data.dimensions.split('x')[0]),
   set_as_background: image_data.set_as_background
 })
}
```

The important part is the call to `fabric_canvas.update` which looks like this:

```
update: function(options) {
  let img_height;
  this.background_image = (options.set_as_background ? options.image_url : null);
  this.height = img_height = (options.set_as_background ? options.image_height : 1000);
  this.background_width = options.image_width;

  this.my_fabric_canvas.setDimensions({
    width: this.width,
    height: img_height
  });
}
```

For some reason, `img_height` is always set to `1000`, even though `options.set_as_background` is `true`.

I've tested `typeof options.set_as_background` which is correctly a boolean.

If I explicitly change the expression to be `img_height = (true ? 100 : 1000)`, I finally get 100 instead.

I'm out of ideas for what might be the cause. `updateBackgroundImage` is called in the `.done` function of an AJAX call (in case this is somehow an async problem, even though it's in `.done`)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm sure the ternary operator itself isn't the problem, it doesn't care if its operands are object properties or not. Note that if `options.set_as_background` *is* true the value set comes from `options.image_height` - is that `1000`?
 You don't make it clear where you were testing with `typeof`. If you `console.log(options.set_as_background, options.image_height, img_height)` immediately after the line with the ternary, what does it say?

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint in your browser's debugger? I'd put one on the `let img_height` line and step through from there

Comment: try in `updateBackgroundImage` to log the values you are passing: `console.log(image_data.dimensions,parseInt(image_data.dimensions.split('x')[1],10))`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I appreciate you all taking the time to help debug.
I should have been clearer that I didn't actually blame the ternary, but rather it was where I noticed the issue.
I found the issue, and will post the answer.
The debugging advice helped me refocus my efforts.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. And while the problem itself is probably too specific to my situation to be of much help for anybody else, the debugging process might be helpful for anybody who comes across this post.

I had previously used `console.log` and `debugger` to see what the values are, but I didn't go all the way through the end until now (because the values I was getting were not obviously askew).

Long story short, I got the correct values at every step through the debugger, but the canvas did not size correctly unless I directly plugged a value into the `setDimensions` method. (I still don't know why this ever worked, and it was a red herring)

The actual problem was that, in the process of defining `fabric_canvas`, it was actually creating a separate instance of the object. So, I was setting the height correctly, but I was setting it on the wrong canvas compared to what was being viewed on the page.

One of those incredibly dumb mistakes.

The key to debugging was seeing that, in fact, the canvas was given the correct height after `setDimensions` and that leading me to think something else was firing afterward to overwrite it. So I viewed the array of instances and noticed there was an extra one being created, rather than the correct one being updated.